# Partial template specialization for variadic template where [Args...] is empty

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, partial-specialization

I have a class, `Delegate`, declared like this:

```
template<typename T> class Delegate;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Delegate<R(Args...)>
{ /*...*/ };
```

It can be instantiated for a function returning a `ReturnType` and taking no arguments as a `Delegate<ReturnType()>`. I've run into an issue that requires me to specialize the class' `()` operator for this case, but haven't been able to figure out how to coerce the compiler doing so without a compiler error.

I have the following function:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
R Delegate<R(Args...)>::operator()(Args... args)
{ /*...*/ }
```

Adding the following specialization, I get an an error saying `invalid use of incomplete type 'class Delegate<R()>'`:

```
template <typename R>
R Delegate<R()>::operator()()
{ /*...*/ }
```

but I can't simply replace `Args...` with `void` either, as far as I've been able to tell... What is the proper procedure here, and (if this question applies and you are feeling extra helpful) why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your attempt with using `R Delegate<R()>::operator()()` to specialize *even more* the member function of a partial specialization of a class template fails due to §14.5.5.3 [temp.class.spec.mfunc]:

> <sup>1</sup> The template parameter list of a member of a class template partial specialization shall match the template parameter list of the class template partial specialization.

In other words:

```
template <typename R>
R Delegate<R()>::operator()() { /**/ }
```

is actually a specialization of `operator()` of your *primary template*:

```
template <typename T>
class Delegate;
```

and since it's an incomplete type, you end up with the error. The possible workarounds are:

#### Option #1

Specialize the entire class and reimplement all the members of that class:

```
template <typename T>
class Delegate;

template <typename R, typename... Args> // partial specialization for non-empty Args
class Delegate<R(Args...)>
{
    R operator()(Args...) { return {}; }
};

template <typename R> // partial specialization for empty Args
class Delegate<R()>
{
    R operator()() { return {}; }
};
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/379d867cdf177ba0)

#### Option #2

Use a one more delegate class that is specialized:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct Impl;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct Impl<R(Args...)>
{
    static R call(Args&&...) { return {}; }
};

template <typename R>
struct Impl<R()>
{
    static R call() { return {}; }
};

template <typename T>
class Delegate;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Delegate<R(Args...)>
{
    R operator()(Args... args)
    {
        return Impl<R(Args...)>::call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55b3297dd7e65bb3)

#### Option #3

Use some ugly SFINAE:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Delegate;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Delegate<R(Args...)>
{
    template <typename T = R>
    typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) != 0 && std::is_same<T,R>{}, R>::type
    operator()(Args...) { return {}; }

    template <typename T = R>
    typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == 0 && std::is_same<T,R>{}, R>::type
    operator()() { return {}; }
};
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed4318f7e1a288ba)

#### Option #4

Inherit from a specialized class template, possibly utilizing the *CRTP* idiom:

```
template <typename T>
class Delegate;

template <typename T>
struct Base;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct Base<Delegate<R(Args...)>>
{
    R operator()(Args...)
    {
        Delegate<R(Args...)>* that = static_cast<Delegate<R(Args...)>*>(this);
        return {};
    }
};

template <typename R>
struct Base<Delegate<R()>>
{
    R operator()()
    {
        Delegate<R()>* that = static_cast<Delegate<R()>*>(this);
        return {};
    }
};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Delegate<R(Args...)> : public Base<Delegate<R(Args...)>>
{
    friend struct Base<Delegate<R(Args...)>>;
};
```

[**DEMO 4**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae9c47c081ac2918)

Comment: @Manu343726 Two words: partial ordering.

Comment: Sorry I didn't note the ordering. My fault. Reading the answer on a small mobile phone :)

Comment: Very nice, @PiotrS. - thank you for spending so much time on this!